# thumbnail not proper genrate of server store file in dropzone

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

I am using this line of code to show the store images on server in my dropzone area its working fine but the thumbnail which is genrated by this is not proper its not show the thumbnail of full image its just zoom the image and then make its thumbnail this is the screenshot of thumbnail https://www.screencast.com/t/PZJjZIN9VJTV
and this is the screenshot of which i want
https://www.screencast.com/t/nwfNbMW2mzFx

```
var mockFile = {
                id:id,
                name:filePath,
                size: '2000',
                type: 'image/jpeg',
                accepted: true            // required if using 'MaxFiles' option
                };
//  this.files.push(mockFile);    // add to files array
this.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
this.emit("thumbnail", mockFile,'http://inspiretech.local/uploads/'+filePath);
this.emit("complete", mockFile);
```

Comment: this isn't related dropzone.js
you need to add some css codes. In your upload file add new .css file. 
and change dz-image (as i known its dz-image, idk).

Comment: sorry did you understand my question what i m trying to ask

Answer (score 1):

this answer comes a couple of years late, but in case it helps shorten the search time of other fellow users.
I found an easy way to solve this issue:

thanks to [makitweb](https://makitweb.com/how-to-display-existing-files-on-server-in-dropzone-php/) tutorial =>

have css correct your image size like so:

```
.dz-preview .dz-image img{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```